# How can I incorporate assembly files in iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode, assembly, cocoapods

I just got two different assembly files for the same function, one is for armv7, and the other one is for arm64.

My question is how should I configure my Xcode project, or my Cocoapods, to add assembly files to architectures respectively? I.e., I want to add the first assembly when building for armv7 architecture, while add the second assembly when building for arm64 architecture.